# When extending MongoItemReader that has stepScope, all fields fill with null value but if use MongoItemReader instead, everything is ok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, partition

I'm using local partitioning in the spring batch along with the MongoDb database.
I created a SubscriptionReader that extends MongoItemReader.

```
    public class SubscriptionReader<T>  extends MongoItemReader<T> implements InitializingBean {
private MongoOperations template;
private Query query;
private String queryString;

    // and other private fields with setter methods and custom implementation of DoPageRead method.
```

This is JobConfig class:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public class JobConfig

{
...

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public SubscriptionReader<Subscription> reader()
        {
            Map<String, Sort.Direction> sorts = new HashMap<>();
            sorts.put("_id", Sort.Direction.ASC);
            SubscriptionReader<Subscription> reader = new SubscriptionReader<>();
                    reader.setCollection("subscription");
                    reader.setQuery(query(null, null, null));

                    reader.setTemplate(template);
                    reader.setName("reader");
                    reader.setTargetType(Subscription.class);
                    reader.setPageSize(20000000);
    return reader;
        }
```

If I replace SubscriptionReader with MongoItemReader, everything is ok but all fields of SubscriptionReader are null when spring creates partitioned steps.
Edit:
I get exception when afterPropertiesSet method of my class calls and it checks for nullability. If I remove that, I'll get a nullPointerException.
Thanks in advance for your time and attention.

Comment: They aren't `null` on the actual/real instance, but only on the proxy. The method calls will pass through the proxy to set the underlying instance.

Comment: I second what @M.Deinum said. Do you have an error? a `NullPointerException`? Please add more details about your issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: Yes. I get exception when afterPropertiesSet method of my class calls and it checks for nullability. If I remove that, I'll get nullPointerException.